# Setting up Xen on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (64bit) from a precompiled kernel

Tags: ubuntu, xen, ubuntu-10.04

I'm looking for a way to install Xen(Dom0) on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit without having to compile my own kernel.

I used to do this for 8.04 using this precompiled kernel:
http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-8.04-server-install-xen-from-ubuntu-repositories

But I cant't find something similar for 10.04.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I decided to run Debian Sqeeuze for my Dom0, because Ubuntu doesn't really have Xen Dom0 support. They have domU kernels (even though since 2.6.32 that is no longer necessary), but no hypervisor (the part between kernel and hardware). I don't really remember, but it wasn't a "we use KVM so forget Xen" thing. I think it had to do with support difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

As Halfgaar said, Ubuntu doesn't really support Dom0 kernel.

As you mentioned, there is a workaround for Intrepid, and you can find a workaround for Jaunty here: http://www.infohit.net/blog/post/compiling-a-xen-dom0-kernel-for-ubuntu-jaunty.html

But I would recommend compiling your own kernel for Lucid. It's pretty straightforward. I did it several times and it worked perfectly. Just follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

It also gives more information about Xen and Ubuntu controversal relation.